# Como llenar una lista que tiene una lista anidada c#

Tags: c#, .net

Buenas tardes,

Trato de llenar una lista con la siguiente estructura :

### LISTA PRINCIPAL->

```
[DataContract]

public class Movimientos

{

public string _id, _IdMovimiento, _Hechopor, _Nombre, _Nodoc;

[DataMember]
public List<MovimientoDet> Items { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public string Id
{
    get { return _id; }
    set { _id = value; }
}

[DataMember]
public string Nodoc
{
    get { return _Nodoc; }
    set { _Nodoc = value; }
}

[DataMember]
public string Nombre
{
    get { return _Nombre; }
    set { _Nombre = value; }
}

[DataMember]
public string Hechopor
{
    get { return _Hechopor; }
    set { _Hechopor = value; }
}

[DataMember]
public string IdMovimiento
{
    get { return _IdMovimiento; }
    set { _IdMovimiento = value; }
}

}
```

**LISTA ANIDADA->**

```
[DataContract]

public class MovimientoDet

{

public string _IdProducto, _Producto, _Cantidad, _Lote;

[DataMember]
public string Lote
{
    get { return _Lote; }
    set { _Lote = value; }
}

[DataMember]
public string Cantidad
{
    get { return _Cantidad; }
    set { _Cantidad = value; }
}

[DataMember]
public string Producto
{
    get { return _Producto; }
    set { _Producto = value; }
}

[DataMember]
public string IdProducto
{
    get { return _IdProducto; }
    set { _IdProducto = value; }
}

}
```

Codigo para llenar la lista(No me funciona cuando intento llenar la lista anidada) :

```
 List<< Movimientos >> lista = new List<< Movimientos >>();

 lista.Add(new Movimientos() {

 Id = "1",

 IdMovimiento = "1345",

 Hechopor = "dsmdk",

 Nombre = "Prueba",

 Nodoc = "Pdsmskdlv",

 Items = ????????

 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En vez de `List<<Movimiento>>` debe de ser `List<Movimiento>`.

Para inicializar a lista dentro de la clase `Movimiento` seria asi:

```
lista.Add(new Movimientos() {

  Id = "1",
  IdMovimiento = "1345",
  Hechopor = "dsmdk",
  Nombre = "Prueba",
  Nodoc = "Pdsmskdlv",
  Items = new List<MomovientoDto>()
 });
```

Solo que no podras agregar nada a lista, por lo que te recomendaria:

```
var movimientosDto = new List<MomovientoDto>()
lista.Add(new Movimientos() {
  Id = "1",
  IdMovimiento = "1345",
  Hechopor = "dsmdk",
  Nombre = "Prueba",
  Nodoc = "Pdsmskdlv",
  Items =  movimientosDto 
}); 

movimientosDto.Add(new MovimientoDto{
   IdMovimiento = 44,
   //...
});
```

Recuerda que también puedes [inicializar la lista con 1 o mas objetos directamente en su declaración](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer). En este caso la lista(solo lo pongo como ejemplo):

```
lista.Add(new Movimientos() {

  Id = "1",
  IdMovimiento = "1345",
  Hechopor = "dsmdk",
  Nombre = "Prueba",
  Nodoc = "Pdsmskdlv",
  Items = new List<MomovientoDto>() 
   { 
     new MovimientoDto{  IdMovimiento = 44, HechoPor = "dsmdk" }
   }
 });
```

Intenta separar cada inicializacion por partes para que no te confundas tanto:

```
List<Movimientos> movimientos = new List<Movimientos>();

// inicializamos una instancia de movimiento
Movimiento mov1 = new Movimiento();
// inicializamos una lista de items dentro de la clase Movimiento
mov1.Items = new List<MovimientoDto>();

// ahora agregamos los MovimientoDto a la propiedad Items
mov1.Items.Add(new MovimientoDto{
 Id = "1",
 IdMovimiento = "1345",
 Hechopor = "dsmdk",
 Nombre = "Prueba",
 Nodoc = "Pdsmskdlv",
});

// y gregamos a la lista movimientos el movimiento y sus items
movimientos.Add(mov1);
```

Comment: Excelente explicación realizare las pruebas necesarias , muchas gracias por su ayuda mi estimado.